# Use regular expression to change column names

Tags: r, gsub

the df column names are for instance:

```
split_the_tree1.zip.name, split_the_tree2.zip.region, split_the_tree3.zip.type
```

I would like to remove everything that comes before `'.zip.'` including the `'.zip.'`

To end up with column names: `name, region, type`

I tried something like this:

```
gsub(".*\zip\/", "", colnames(df))

gsub('*.zip', '', colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
colnames(df) <- gsub('.*zip.', '', colnames(df))
```

Note that we have `.*` and not `*.`

Although the quick way to do this is to note that the names you want are simply stored as extensions, hence use `tools::file_ext` function

```
strings <- c("split_the_tree1.zip.name", "split_the_tree2.zip.region", 
             "split_the_tree3.zip.type")

tools::file_ext(strings)
[1] "name"   "region" "type"
```